# Scrolling over highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, highcharts

Here's my issue:
I am using the phonegap framework to develop a hybrid app, and I need this application to have graphs for which I had decided to use the highcharts library.

The problem is that I can't seem to be able to scroll after touching on the chart (at least while touching inside the selected portion of the image).

[image: ios graph]

What I want to do is prevent the chart from taking any events and show a plain graph with anything being highlighted and be able to scroll even if im doing it over the graph.

Code:

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'containerBar',
    animation: false,
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      click: function(event){
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      events: {
        click: function(event){
          return false;
        },
        mouseOver: function(event){
          return false;           
        },
        legendItemClick: function () {
          return false;
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: function(){
          alert("Allow");
        }
      }
    }
  },
  events: {
    click: function(e) {
      alert("Click");
    }  
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit eaten'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 3, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 7, 3]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Use Highstock. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/spline

Comment: If you just want to show a plain graph, then why are you using such a heavy library like Highcharts? I would prefer something like Google Chart Tools.

Comment: @HardikMishra Highstock seems to have the same problem ..

Comment: @keune This is just for a kind of POC , There will be more graphs in the actual application

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi everybody , I was also having the same problem but now there is a fix if you use the latest version(5.0.9) you can scroll over the graph  .They fixed this problem on Highcharts 5.0 . For now v5.0.9 is fixed you can use it . https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js link goes to v5.0.9 ,However when I download and use the zip bundle it gave me some errors as pointed in the link https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/chart-is-solid-black-after-upgrade-to-5-0-t36551/ Correct way is to copy code from https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js .Hope I can help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To follow up for folks reading this question and its answers, the issue with scrolling and Highcharts visualizations was resolved with Version 3.0.1 (2013-04-09). Highstock, a sibling of Highcharts, received a similar update with Version 1.3.1 (2013-04-09).

> Added new option, tooltip.followTouchMove. When this is true, the
>   tooltip can be moved by dragging a single finger across the chart,
>   like in Highcharts 2. When it is false, dragging a single finger is
>   ignored by the chart, and causes the whole page to scroll. This
>   applies only when zooming is not enabled.

Further enhancements were made in Highcharts Version 4.1.0 (2015-02-16):

> Made tooltip.followTouchMove true by default, and allowed page scroll
>   at the same time.

For the complete Highcharts change log, see http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had to make sure and nest the `followTouchMove: false` attribute under the top-level `tooltip` chart option. That way it would apply to each series and their respective graphs. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

Try this [link](https://gist.github.com/2994906) .... 
Just make a separate javascript file ,copy paste the code and include the file

Comment: It works, but get js errors saying mouseTracker.normalizeMouseEvent is not defined. Fortunately, I'm only using this for mobile, so commented out that "normalize" stuff. (Or could just wrap it in a try/catch).

Comment: That worked great! Why not create an issue for Highcharts so they can incorporate it to their repo?

Comment: Worked a treat and made my Friday!

Comment: For me `chart.tracker` is undefined. Any hints? Did they just rename the property?

Comment: Found it. It´s `chart.pointer`. There are also forks for newer versions like this: https://gist.github.com/sehv/928f356afd6b68eb28e2. Unfortunately zooming into diagrams is not working anymore with this script

Comment: @Aatish, I don't think this should be the accepted answer. I think it is bad practice to try and add external extensions to a library without reading it's documentation thoroughly. Simply setting `tooltip.followTouchMove: false` as stated [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followTouchMove) in their documentation did the trick for me and I assume would for you pending I read your question correctly. Didn't have to add an external JS file or hack their library code. ALWAYS READ THE DOCS :)

Comment: @BenS:
I don't have the time to test this but I'm going to take the documentations word for it and updating it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by Highcharts capturing all touch events and making them do nothing. I solved this by basically just overlaying a div over the chart area on mobile devices and preventing those events from reaching highcharts elements (so they are free to trigger default behavior, i.e. page scrolling). I used this JS (assuming you are also using JQuery or equivalent):

```
$('.highcharts-container').each(function() {
  var dragHandle;
  dragHandle = $('<div class="chart-drag-handle">');
  $(this).append(dragHandle);
  dragHandle.on('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  dragHandle.on('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  dragHandle.on('touchend', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  dragHandle.on('touchcancel', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

The elements added would need to be styled to overlay the chart, I did that like so:

```
.highcharts-container .chart-drag-handle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to define the same function 4 times - you can do `var stopProp = function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); };` then use `dragHandle.on('touchstart', stopProp);`, or even better, jQuery.on will take a comma separated list of events: `dragHandle.on('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`