# Scrolling on mobile device using Highcharts and touchpunch

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am attempting to use Highcharts in a web application for mobile, but I'm running into the issue of scrolling over the charts on mobile as has been previously noted, i.e. [Scrolling over highcharts graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156245/scrolling-over-highcharts-graph/12625903#12625903).

I tried including the script touch-tooltip-fix.js - https://gist.github.com/skarface/2994906

This however doesn't work for me, neither do the other similar scripts that I've found online that are supposed to solve the issue. I'm wondering if the issue is that I'm using jQuery UI touch-punch? I've tried modifying the script but haven't had any luck.

Basically my questions are is this fixed now? And if so is there a way I can get it to work with touch-punch (or is that even the issue)?

Comment: Make sure you have up-to-date version of Highcharts (4.1.9). It should work properly. If not, check this option: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.followTouchMove

Comment: Hi Pawel, I do have Highcharts 4.1.9, and I tried the followTouchMove option but it didn't work. The problem for me isn't the tooltips, it's the entire chart. I need to be able to still scroll down when swiping over the chart, and because on mobile I have to increase the size of the charts for them to be seen, then this leaves no space on the screen to swipe and move the page.